# Edgecolor of violinplot in Seaborn is not determined by the hue

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I have created a violinplot substantially similar to one in the Seaborn gallery:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="whitegrid", palette="pastel", color_codes=True)

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

sns.violinplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="sex", data=tips, split=True,
           inner="quart", palette={"Male": "b", "Female": "y"})
sns.despine(left=True)
```

However, I have been unable to vary the edgecolor by hue ("Male" and "Female" in the example above). A previous answer on Stack Exchange solved this problem in the context of a Seaborn stripplot, but the geometry of the violinplot appears to require a different solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is just how seaborn's violinplot currently works. In the source code (`site-packages/seaborn/distributions.py`, in `violinplot()`:

```
    for side in [-1, 1]:
        ax_plot((side * dens) + x, y, c=gray, lw=lw)
```

so:

*When you find it on your system you can edit it.*

The docstring is explicit that the color arguments are for the inside of the violins:

> ```
> color : mpl color, sequence of colors, or seaborn palette name
>         Inner violin colors
> ```

Comment: Correct answer; the color isn't intended to be mapped to arbitrary plot elements.